# Find the expected amount of people you must sample before you encounter 3 people with a specific trait that only 44 out of the 100 people have

Tags: combinatorics, expected-value

I was going through my Statistics class homework earlier today, and I found an interesting question in the textbook that I wasn't sure how to approach. So the problem goes a little like this:

> A person with type O-positive blood can receive blood only from other type O donors. About $44\%$ of the U.S. population has type O blood. At a blood drive, how many potential donors do you expect to examine in order to get three units of type O blood?

The textbook wanted us to set up a simulation on how to get an estimate, but I was also interested in calculating the exact expected value using more combinatorics-related methods. But the issue is I'm not exactly sure how to do it. Normally with a smaller set of values, I would manually brute force through each scenario. But the issue is with this problem, I would have to at the least set up a group of $100$ people, with $44$ of them with the type-O blood. And that's a bit too much to brute force through. So I wanted to come here to ask if anyone knows a more efficient approach to this problem or even a general formula to find the exact expected value.

Comment: Well, you expect to have to see $\frac 1{.44}$ people before you find a single $O$.  Can you finish from there?

Comment: Note:  solving the problem exactly with $100$ people would only give you an approximation.  It would be better to sample with infinitely many people, which you can do by assuming that each draw independently has a $.44$ success probability.

Comment: @lulu Yes, I can see your logic. But I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Would I add the $\frac{1}{.44}$ to itself $3$ times ($1$ time for each person)?

Comment: Have you worked with probability distributions yet? If so, are you familiar with the [Negative Binomial Distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution)?

Comment: @WaveX I do not think I have worked with probability distributions just yet.

Comment: @BorisPoris  Yes.  all you have to do is multiply the $\frac 1{.44}$ by $3$.  Worth confirming this by simulation!

Comment: @lulu Thanks! I wasn't aware we could just calculate the expected value for a single O and multiply it by the number of people we need to collect. That seems like a really good method for future problems I might encounter like this as well.

Comment: Just think of it inductively. you have to sample people until you get that first $O$.  You expect that to take you $\frac 1{.44}$ people.  Now you keep going till you get the second $O$.  Well, that is expected to take another $\frac 1{.44}$ people.  And so on.